# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting function (T_FUNCTION) inmodule\Album\Module.php on line 25

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks

I have error on my module.php.

I got the code [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/modules.html).

I am following the instructions but I don't know where I get it wrong.

Please see my code below:

```
    <?php
namespace Album;

class Module
{
    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
            ),
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }
```

Comment: what is on `Module.php on line 25` ?

Comment: I wonder why you can make a `return` statement without being inside a function....

Comment: @GBD
Actually it's line 23 which is "}" end of public function getConfig()

Comment: @luiges90 I got it from Zend Framework tutorial

Comment: I think you forgot to close `}` `class`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code lacks closing bracket at the end. Add `}` at the end of your script, to close `class` block